# Mapping of Columns in Kendo-Grid in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The below is the code I have used to populate the Kendo-Grid with `Observable<GridDataResult>`

```
<kendo-grid [data]="usersDataView | async" [height]="425" [pageSize]="pageSize" [skip]="skip"
        [pageable]="true" [kendoGridBinding]="data" (pageChange)="onPageChange($event)" [sort]="state.sort"
        (selectionChange)="selectionChanged($event)" [groupable]="false" [group]="state.group" [columnMenu]="true"
        [resizable]="true">
<kendo-grid-column showSelectAll="true" [width]="60" [minResizableWidth]="60">
    <ng-template kendoGridHeaderTemplate let-column let-columnIndex="columnIndex">
      <input type="checkbox" (click)="SetAllSelected($event)" />
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.selected"
        [attr.disabled]="dataItem.deviceName !== null  ? true : null" (click)=SetSelectedItem(dataItem) />
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column field="userName" title={{translations.USER_NAME}} filter="text" [filterable]="true"
    headerClass="kendoColumn">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <a *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 0"
        [routerLink]="['/users/details/'+dataItem.userd]">{{dataItem.userName}}</a>
      <span *ngIf="dataItem.userStatus === 1">{{dataItem.userName}}</span>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

When I run the App, it populates the Grid with Empty rows but equals to the no. of records in the data. I am finding difficulty in mapping the columns to the Grid.

What change I have to do with `usersDataView` collection and populate the data in the Grid?

Comment: Is there anyone out there to resolve my issue?

Comment: Can you provide us with sample data that you're trying to populate the grid with?

Comment: @David I am able to map the columns now. The problem is with returning proper data from the `WebApi`. Thanks a lot for your response.